# Clear Text of All Textboxes in Selected Tab

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a form that has a `tab control` and each tab has a number of `textboxes`,`labels` and `buttons`. I want to enable the user to clear all text in the textboxes of the selected tab.

I have tried

```
    private void resetCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBox t in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
        {
            t.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

The above code throw an `InvalidCastException` with the Message `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`.

Pls what did i do wrong and how can i correct it?

Comment: You want controls.oftype<textbox>()

Comment: @Sayse Pls where do i put it?. I use visual c# 2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this online and it worked

```
    void ClearTextBoxes(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null)
                ClearTextBoxes(child);
            else
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void resetCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearTextBoxes(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `OfType<T>()` in the foreach loop.

```
private void resetCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox t in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        t.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Alternative:

```
foreach (Control control in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls) 
{
    TextBox text = control as TextBox;
    if (text != null) 
    {
        text.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Intellisence doesn't display `OfType<T>()`. I use Visual C# 2005

Comment: It's available from .NET 3.5 and higher. Another alternative is to safely cast it to a TextBox and check if its not null. I shall add an example to my answer

Comment: You also need to include the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Otherwise there if control is textbox

Comment: @ScottChamberlain according to the MSDN Documentation it's available for .NET 3.5 and higher so in his case he can't use it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No `System.Linq` in C# 2005 
@MartijnvanPut The alternative doesn't perform any action

Comment: I know that, I was adding the comment for future visitors of the site who are doing the same thing but using 2008 or newer.

Comment: @Precious1tj ive tested the statement and it works in my case check Ehsan Ullah's answer in case the textBox lives in an child control.

Answer (score 1):

Use can simply iterate through all the controls in the selected tab and before clearing the text check if the `control type` is `TextBox` and clear the text.

```
 foreach (Control item in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
            {
                if (item.GetType().Equals(typeof(TextBox)))
                {
                    item.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your if statement can be simplified to `if(item is TextBox)`

Comment: Still doesn't perform any action

Comment: @Coder You must be using a higher version of c#

Comment: My mistake, i'm using framework 4.0. Glad you have found the solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if you have textboxes nested in your tabcontrol. you need to write a recursive method here as `ofType` method **will not return** your nested textboxes..

```
 private void ResetTextBoxes(Control cntrl)
 {
     foreach(Control c in cntrl.Controls)
     {
          ResetTextBoxes(c);
          if(c is TextBox)
            (c as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
     }
 }
```

Alternatively if you have got textboxes only on the base level of TabControl you can use this

```
foreach(var tb in tabControl1.OfType<TextBox>())
 {
    tb.Text = string.Emtpy;
}
```

Comment: Good point, without this text boxes inside other controls (panels, group boxes, ect) will not be cleared.

Comment: I get the error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' because 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: The foreach is a bit wrong it needs to bo: foreach(Control c in cntrl.Controls)

Comment: @Precious1tj edited. Thanks Martijn. This is the problem when you are typing directly into the editor and not IDE.

Comment: @MartijnvanPut Still doesn't perform any action

Comment: That could be true indeed, it's better to pass an ControlCollection because how you're gonna start this loop? Which control do you pass in:)

Comment: @MartijnvanPut `tabControl1.SelectedTab`

Comment: @Precious1tj i would really like to have your code that you have tried, because it is really straight forward.

Comment: @EhsanUllah I added the answer i saw online that worked for me

Comment: @Precious1tj yeah i have seen that, was curious why my answer didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var textBoxNames = this.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
            foreach (var item in textBoxNames)
            {
                var textBoxes = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Find(item.Name, true);
                foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxes)
                {
                    textBox.Clear();
                }
            }
```